# Nesting a jquery selector in a string seems to have issues being valid

Tags: jquery

I have to have a script in a string, and it seems to not quite be right.

```
$("input,textarea").
   find("[feId=1234]").
      val("SET_VALUE").
         css("background-color","yellow");
```

is what i am trying to do first, so that needs to be correct.  was getting all the base elements and then find the element  with attribute 'feId' with value '1234'.

After that, i was trying to just get it swapped out but escaping stuff such as below.

```
"$(\"input,textarea\").
   find(\"[feId=1234]\").
     val(\"SET_VALUE\").
        css(\"background-color\",\"yellow\");"
```

but it wasnt seeming to work.   I an thinking that my attribute selector might be wrong ever so slightly?

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What is it that isn't working? What are you trying to do with the escaped string afterwards?

Comment: You do know you can combine those selectors to `input[feId=1234], textarea[feId=1234]`?

Comment: And don't set styles in code... Rather toggle CSS classes and provide styles in CSS files. You'll thank me after a month or so. :)

Comment: well, for some reason, it isnt selecting the fields correctly.  It is suppose to set the content of an inputbox/textarea to the contents of VAL and change the background color, based on a given ID (feId) equaling a given number.   It doesnt seem to select anything and change any colors which i find is odd.

Comment: You want `.filter("[feId=1234]")`, not `.find`.  `.find` searches children of the elements, `.filter` looks at the elements themselves.

Comment: Why does this need to be in a string?  What are you doing with it?  You're not `eval`ing it are you?

Comment: No, i am building scripts in Objective-C for custom, dynamic HTML files and their associated Javascript.

Comment: I noticed all the elements didnt have IDs, so i just shifted them all to be ID's and then just did a similar search, using filter as above...  and it worked!